# Capybara webkit doesn't pass params from angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, capybara-webkit

I am trying to port a selenium test suite to capybara-webkit. The Rails app has an angular app embedded in the rails views and is not behaving as expected with `webkit`.

A test like this:

require 'spec_helper'

```
feature 'Editing company profiles' do
  before do
    @user = create(:employee)
    @company = Company.find(@user.employer.id)
    sign_in_as! @user
  end

  scenario 'successfully', js: true do
    click_link 'Dashboard'
    click_link @company.name
    click_button 'Edit'
    fill_in 'company_name', with: 'new name'
    click_button 'Save'

    expect(page).to have_content "Your company profile has been updated!"
  end
end
```

Will pass without issue in selenium, but with `webkit` I get the error

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: company
 # ./app/controllers/api/v1/companies_controller.rb:23:in `company_params'
 # ./app/controllers/api/v1/companies_controller.rb:10:in `update'
```

The trace is missing, maybe because it's from angular land, but the error is reporting that no params are coming from the client. I've tried the `capybara-angular` gem, but it has not helped. I've also tried saving the page with capybara and nothing looks out of place there, are there any ways to access the `PATCH` request inside of webkit that's being generated in this test? I've also gotten similar errors with `poltergeist`.

Has anyone setup headless rspec testing with angular + rails? Any tips on how to debug why data isn't being sent over from the client?

Comment: I have some experience with Capybara and WebKit on a rails-angular app. Some tests do not work without selenium, but I'm willing to take a look. Can you post the AngularJS template and controller rendering the page in this test?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code, this feels like it could be a problem associated with a [known issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/553) in the [capybara-webkit gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) is unable to pass entity bodies to the server.

I suspect that the update request is being sent as a `PATCH` request (which is appropriate), but the issue with the gem results in failure for your tests.

A workaround to your problem is to change the method of the request to `PUT` or `POST`, the issue linked above shows some options.  You will be able to get your test to pass, but it's up to you to decide if changing the request type is worth getting your test to pass.

**Note:** In practice it may not matter if you don't actually use `PATCH`, as you could technically use (*some of*) the other http methods interchangeably -- but use caution as there are reasons to use a specific http method for a given situation.  See this [rubyonrails.org](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) post from a few years ago for some details.

Comment: this is the exact issue, my angular service was using `patch`, switched to `put` and it passes the params correctly, thanks. will award bounty in 5 hours when it lets me

Comment: I am having same issue with phantomjs and poltergeist using with Capybara. So the same issue with phantomjs and poltergeist?