# Testing JQuery Upload in Capybara: Files are not attaching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara-webkit, jquery-upload-file-plugin

I am currently building a rails app that uses the jquery-upload plugin to allows users to upload files to do things such as set their user avatar.  If the upload is successful, it sets a hidden field on the form with the upload ID, and when the form is submitted, the association is saved.  When I manually test this, it works the way it is supposed to.  However, I cannot get my RSpec tests to pass.

I am using RSpec as my testing framework and Capybara-webkit as my javascript drive.  The field where the file is supposed to attach looks like this

`= file_field_tag :file, class: "upload_file_field"`

(Also, using slim for templating)

The coffeescript that handles the file upload looks like this

```
$element.fileupload
  dropZone: $dropzoneElement
  url: "/uploads.json"
  method: "PATCH"
  fail: (e, data) =>
    @showErrorOnFailure(e, data)
  done: (e, data) =>
    @onSuccessfulUpload(e, data)
```

Controller code that handles file uploads looks like this

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(file: params[:file])

    byebug

    if @upload.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {upload: @upload, url: @upload.file.url(:avatar) } }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: {}, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the RSpec code I am using in the test to attach the file

```
filepath = "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/fixtures/uploads/flickr.jpg"
attach_file :file, filepath

click_on "Submit"

expect(page).to have_css(".avatar-img img")
```

When I run the test, the entire request goes through (Capybara does not indicate it had trouble finding the file or the form field).  However, the test fails.  And when I use byebug to inspect the uploads controller at the point it receives the request to save a new upload, there are no parameters being sent.  As in `params[:file]` evaluates to `nil`, when it should have the file information for `flickr.jpg`.  Any idea why my file isn't attaching in the test, even though Capybara isn't raising any errors about it.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading through this post I found an answer:

[Capybara webkit doesn't pass params from angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808826/capybara-webkit-doesnt-pass-params-from-angular)

It looks like the problem came from the fact that I was using PATCH to send the uploads.  After changing the method to PUT, my tests started passing.